# Application of DCT to show Mill's ratio for $N(0,1)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Good day everyone,

We want to show $\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}dt \sim\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem(DCT) for standard normal distribution.

The problem is I don't see where the expected value (that is used in DCT) comes in! Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the substitutionq $s=t-x$ and $u:=xs$, we are reduced to show that 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{x^2}\right)\exp(-u)\mathrm du=1.$$
This follows from the *monotone* convergence theorem.

Hence there is no need to use *dominated* convergence (nevertheless, dominated convergence also holds since $u\mapsto e^{-u}\chi_{(0,+\infty)}(u)$ is an integrable dominating function).

Comment: @did Thanks for the edits.